# How to set 2 launchers for an application?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

I have added a radio activity to my application and i want this to be an option to seperating launcher. So editing androidmanifest will not work for me(i guess). 
I tried this on my Settings activity but i didn't see any difference.

```
radiolauncherswitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.radiolauncherswitch);

    if(!read("radyolauncher")) radiolauncherswitch.setChecked(false); else  radiolauncherswitch.setChecked(true); 
    radiolauncherswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                save("radyolauncher",true);
                Intent launcher = new Intent(Settings.this,Radyo.class);
                launcher.addCategory("CATEGORY_LAUNCHER");


            } else {
                save("radyolauncher",false);
                Intent launcher = new Intent(Settings.this,Radyo.class);
                launcher.removeCategory("CATEGORY_LAUNCHER");

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: I feel you should totally drop the idea of having two launchers for the same app. I don't think it is any way to do it. There cannot be two entry points to the same app.

Comment: @pskink i want to add another launcher app icon in main screen that goes directly to that activity and i want it to be an option.

Comment: @Code_Yoga you can have multiple Activities with <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> whats the problem?

Comment: so add another Activity with <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: @pskink but when user switches off on settings i want that icon disapper.

Comment: disappear from a home launcher? no you cannot do that

Comment: ok in theory you can do that, try: `PackageManager#setComponentEnabledSetting`, maybe it will work

Comment: @pskink thanks, i am trying it now